# Understanding rails variable persistence with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, object

When I create a new object via a scaffolded controller, if I actionate some jquery script into my form and that these scripts trigger a function in my controller, this function doesn't know about the object I just created. Why?

Let me explain:

In my controller, I first create my object:

```
  def new
    @projectmilestone = Projectmilestone.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @projectmilestone }
    end
  end
```

In my view, I have a form with one nested partial:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:projects,@projectmilestone]  do |form| %>

    <%= form.semantic_errors :state %>
    <%= form.inputs do %>
      <%= form.input :department_id, :as => :select, :collection => Department.all%>
      <div id="stakeholders">
          <%=render :partial => "stakeholders", :locals => {:users => @users }%>
      </div>

    <%  end %>

    <%= form.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

The stakeholders partial is like this:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:projects,@projectmilestone], :remote => true  do |form| %>
    <%= form.inputs :partial do %>
      <%= form.input :user_id , :as => :select, :collection => users %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I change the department_id value, a javascript function is triggered in my application.js file:

```
$('#projectmilestone_department_id').live('change', function() {
    // make a POST call and replace the content
    var department = $('select#projectmilestone_department_id :selected').val();
    if(department == "") department="0";
    var milestone = $('#form_id').html();
    jQuery.get('/projects/projectmilestones/update_user_select/' + department, function(data){
        $("#stakeholders").html(data);
    })
    return false;
  });
```

This function calls the function update_user_select in my controller:

```
 def update_user_select
    users=""
    users = User.where(:department_id=>params[:department_id]) unless params[:department_id].blank?
    render :partial => "stakeholders", :locals => {:users => users }
  end
```

The users partial should then reload in my form but it doesn't because @projectmilestone is nil.

Why is @projectmilestone not persisted when I use this jquery script and persisted when there i go to the create function of my scaffold?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is when Rails renders your page, the instance variable you set in the controller is shared between the view and the partials.
It's part of the stack, server side and sent to the client, in your browser.

But when you use Ajax, you're working from the client and the server doesn't know anymore about what it sent before unless you recall it by sending the id of the object you're working on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The id of the object is not the one that will be set in the db when I'll save (sql insert) the object, right? So how can I send this object id to the controller and have the controller using it in my update_user_select method?

Comment: you're right, it's not the id of the future db object. But to save a single object, you should generate html consistent with the html already existing. Maybe it would be easier to do so manually instead of using the form helpers. You could take inspiration in Ryan Bates code. See https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: I had a look at it but, too complex for me... For now, as a workaround, I added     @projectmilestone = params[:id].to_i != 0 ? Projectmilestone.find(params[:id]) : Projectmilestone.new in my controller function. It seems to do the job despite the fact that it's not very elegant... Thanks!